# Merging multiple non overlapping raster layers into one layer

Tags: qgis, raster, qgis-plugins, merge

[image][image]I'm working in Qgis 2.14 and have received multiple raster files for the Height of a terrain that combined covers the entire terrain I’m interested in.

I would like to combine them. Because the specific areas sometime overlap between two Rasters calculations are difficult.

I have tried using the following tools :

- Raster-> Miscellaneous-> Merge tool
- Raster-> Miscellaneous-> Build Virtual Raster (Catalog)
- Raster-> Miscellaneous-> Build overviews (Pyramids).

However, they all inform me that I either do not have the permission/rights to use these tools or the tools are not installed or have disappeared. Does anyone know is these tools belong to some plugin? 
I have tried to look through the plugins but have not found them. However there are so many I could have missed it!

the top picture is the error message i get when i try to make a catalog of the Raster files.

I have tried to change the folder mentioned in the comments to the first answer but i get the message shown in the button picture.

Comment: I would try running it from a non-Dropbox file. QGIS might not have permission to write/read from Dropbox.

Answer (score 0):

The catalog tool should do the trick. There is an option to select which behaviour you want to use in the overlapping areas.

The tools should be present in the default installation. Check that the processing plugin is installed and it should work.

Comment: The Processing plugin is installed but the catalog tool stil tells me that it cant start. what it tells me is "The process could not start. Either the program is missing, or you may not have enough privileges to launch the program." this has been translated from Danish so it may not be accurate but at least close.

Comment: Could you update to Qgis 2.18, which is the latest long term version? 2.14 is now deprecated.

Also what is your OS?

Comment: Hallo again sorry for the late reply. if you mean my operating system it is Windows 8. also would updating my Qgis make problems for me if i keep using the same projects?

Comment: No worries! I run windows 8.1, but I've never had any problem upgrading Qgis. You might experience minor issues if you try to open a project saved with a newer version of Qgis(2.18) in 2.14, but I've never had any issue opening a project after upgrading. 

I'd strongly recommend upgrading, as there were a lot of improvements since 2.14! Stick with the LTS release though, Qgis 3.0 might still be a bit rough on the angles, wait a bit more if you're unsure. 

To ease the process, you can use OSGeo4W and run it once a month to keep up with the updates.

Comment: Thank you i will properly try that but have to ask my boss first i think.

Comment: You're welcome! Keep me updated with your results!

Comment: Update now that my boss gave me the go ahead. i updated to Qgis 2.18 and i still have the exact same problem.

Comment: try renaming the .qgis2 folder in C:\Users\(Youruser) and opening Qgis again? 
If that doesn't work, could you try editing your answer with a screenshot?

Comment: Sorry my program is using danish as its language so i don't think a screenshot will be much help if you not danish. What should i rename the folder as?

Comment: whatever you want, eg .qgis2old . The idea is to regenerate that folder to see if the error comes from there. This way, you can always put it back in place afterwards. edit : yeah windows... remove the leading point when renaming I guess

Comment: i really don't know whats going wrong i tried installing Qgis for the first time on another computer and the same error occurred. i also tried regenerating the .qgis2 folder. still the same error. what could make the same weird error occur on two different computers?

Comment: Have you tried with only two layers? Also which installation method did you use? Also check that the path specified in processing -> options are correct. Can you write a file in the temp folder specified in Qgis parameters?